# How to accept all my changes, or all their changes in a magit manual merge?

Tags: git, emacs, magit

In magit during a manual merge, sometimes there are files with many changes and I want to accept either all my changes, or all the changes in the other branch, rather than select them one by one. Is there a way to do that within magit, or if not from the git command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for one file during the merge you can:

```
git checkout good_revision file
```

Comment: So in the case that I'm merging with a remote branch, good_revision would just be the branch name?

Comment: Yes you can use a branch name as a revision.